# How to center two text views as center aligned in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How to place two text views `Marked within red rectangle` in relative layouts with center aligned. How can I design as shown in the picture?
 Here text and number both are textviews.

[image]

I have tried the following but I could not get center aligned view to relative layout.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/location_party_size_lbl_layer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_party_size_lbl"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@string/loc_estimate"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location_party_size_lbl_layer"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="1.0">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_party_size"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.48"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/qnowscreen_dummy_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.52"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: perhaps you could use a linearlayout with orientation horizontal and weights on its children?

Comment: @ Ms Yvette ǝʇʇǝʌʎ sW,  location_party_size_lbl is used for showing text "estimated ...." and location_party_size used for showing "2"

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by creating an anchor view and aligning `TextView`s relatively to the anchor.

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
      android:id="@+id/anchor"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It comes vertically center aligned not horizontally center aligned.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood you question. Unfortunately what you want is impossible to implement with a `RelativeLayout`.